# How to zoom in on a image when Image.MouseEnter fires?

Tags: wpf, image, animation, triggers, storyboard

I would like to zoom in on a `Image` when `Image.MouseEnter` fires and then zoom out when `Image.MouseLeave` fires.
I thought of creating a Trigger, but no luck.

This is what i tried so far:

```
    <Image Name="logo" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" 
          Width="50" Height="50">
      <Image.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="TransRotate"  />
      </Image.RenderTransform>
      <Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransRotate" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                         From="0" To="100"
                         BeginTime="0:0:0"
                         Duration="0:0:10"  
                         AutoReverse="False"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransRotate" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                         From="0" To="100"                                                           
                         BeginTime="0:0:0"
                         Duration="0:0:10"
                         AutoReverse="False"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Is this the correct way, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `From` property, this makes the animation jump, apart from that you just seem to be lacking the reverse animations on `MouseLeave`. Also to center the zoom you can set the [`RenderTransformOrigin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) of the `Image` to `0.5,0.5`.

Instead of using those two events i usually prefer a trigger on `IsMouseOver` with [`Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.enteractions.aspx) and [`ExitActions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.exitactions.aspx).

If you want to retain the space the image takes you can place it in a container with fixed size and set `ClipToBounds` to true.

Comment: Thanks for the responce H.B. I did change the code to what u specified, but nothing happens. Am i missing something? Can u maybe post an example of what the `DoubleAnimation` should look like?

Comment: The code in your question does animate for me already, i do not know what kind of image you have or if something around the image is preventing the animation. Copy your own code and try it in a clean environment and it will work.